# When a matrix is merely symmetric?

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be a matrix. I would you like to know when $M$ is merely symmetric? 
And when a matrix $M$ is skew symmetric?
When a matrix is asymmetric?

Comment: Assuming over the real field: Symmetric : $\;A=A^t\;$ , antisymmetric $\;A^t=-A\;$

Answer (score 1):

"Merely symmetric" is not a technical term.

$M$ is said to be *symmetric* if $M=M^{\sf t}$ where $M^{\sf t}$ is the transpose of $M$.

$M$ is said to be *skew-symmetric* if $M=-M^{\sf t}$.

---

(If the field/ring of scalars has characteristic 2, this definition of skew-symmetric doesn't work well. Instead I believe it is usual to generalize to this case by saying that $M$ is skew-symmetric if $X^{\sf T}MX=0$ for all columns $X$. This is equivalent to $M=-M^{\sf t}$ in characteristic $\ne 2$).